# Renaming a column in Pandas grouped By dataframe is failing

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, rename

I have the results of my groupby statements:

```
df_Done_Ccy = df[
                    df['state'].str.contains('Done')
                ][['currency_str','state']]
d = {
                ('state',np.size)   # apply the count of done trades to the following groupby
    }
df_Done_Ccy_Grp = df_Done_Ccy.groupby('currency_str')['state'].agg(d).reset_index() #we reset the index and the old index is added as a column
df_Done_Ccy_Grp['Percentage'] = df_Done_Ccy_Grp['state'].div(df_Done_Ccy['state'].count())

print(df_Done_Ccy_Grp.columns)
display(df_Done_Ccy_Grp.sort_values('state',ascending=False))

Index(['currency_str', 'state', 'Percentage'], dtype='object')
currency_str    state   Percentage
7   USD          146    0.581673
9   ZAR           54    0.215139
3   EUR           24    0.095618
0   AUD           9     0.035857
4   GBP           7     0.027888
2   CAD           6     0.023904
5   NOK           2     0.007968
1   BRL           1     0.003984
6   SEK           1     0.003984
8   Und           1     0.003984
```

Looks good, I just wanted to rename the state column to 'Done Trades'. The following line works when renaming 'currency_str'    or 'Percentage' but fails on 'state' i.e. KeyError: 'state'

```
df_Done_Ccy_Grp = df_Done_Ccy_Grp.rename(columns={'state':'Done Trades'}, level=0) # rename the column header in the groupby
```

What is it about a dataframe's grouped by column which caused this? Is there another way to achieve this?

Peter

Comment: can not be trailing whitespace if this is working display(df_Done_Ccy_Grp.sort_values('state',ascending=False))

Comment: print(df_Done_Ccy_Grp.columns.tolist()) 
['currency_str', 'state', 'Percentage']

Comment: @PeterLucas - OK, it is correct output.

Comment: @PeterLucas - if remove `level=0` still same problem? `df_Done_Ccy_Grp = df_Done_Ccy_Grp.rename(columns={'state':'Done Trades'})` ?

Comment: @PeterLucas - And another idea - Maybe check output dataframe before renaming, what is `display(df_Done_Ccy_Grp)` after `rename` ?

Comment: Same result after removing level=0. But interestingly if I place display(df_Done_Ccy_Grp) after the rename and comment out the 
display(df_Done_Ccy_Grp.sort_values('state',ascending=False)) the rename is successful. Strange. Not sure why a sort would impact a rename

Comment: Works now if I sort on Done Trade
display(df_Done_Ccy_Grp.sort_values('Done Trades',ascending=False))

Answer (score 0):

Sorting on the rename resolved this:

```
df_Done_Ccy_Grp = df_Done_Ccy_Grp.rename(columns={'state':'Done Trades'}, level=0) 

display(df_Done_Ccy_Grp.sort_values('Done Trades',ascending=False)) – Peter Lucas
```